# Can I automate location changing so I don't have to drive the choice manually?

Tags: macos, network, geolocation

Wondering is anyone knows of an application that can change settings on my Macbook Pro depending on the wireless networks it detects?

Ie, If I was at work, connect to the Work Wireless, Change default printer, chance location, change wallpaper etc.

I seem to remember seeing an app at one stage, however after much Googling I cannot find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

AirPort Location** takes snapshots of the system settings you select and re-applies them the next time you use your machine at that location.

** Update Oct 2016: Airport location appears to be no longer maintained, but still available at [MacUpdate.com][2]. It may be limited to older versions of OS-X. The same site suggests [ControlPlane][3] provides similar functionality; I have not used it.

Answer (score 3):

[ControlPanel](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/feature-list/) is an actively maintained, advanced fork of MarcoPolo that works on Mountain Lion. It supports using your GPS location as well as many other factors in determining what various settings should be. I am actually surprised these features haven't been built into the core OS. The source code is on GitHub.

From the site:

> ControlPlane supports multiple contexts where a context is defined as
>   a location or activity you are performing.  Using evidence sources you
>   can create a set of rules that tell ControlPlane what context to apply
>   to your environment.  When ControlPlane enters or leaves a context a
>   set of Actions are performed.

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/)?  It can infer your location from a variety of things (visible wireless networks are one of its "evidence sources"), and adjust settings based on what it finds.

Answer (score -1):

There is one more alternative: [Locader](http://pleeq.com/locader/), right now it changes wallpaper only, but in the future more location based functions will be available.

You can set different places, and when you're there, wallpaper will be changed to the one, that you selected.

Comment: I'm not sure why I got down vote